# Error upon installation of android stuidio

Tags: android, installation

Upon installation of Android Studio there is an error "Can't write: C\Program Files\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\org\apache\apache-9.pom

Comment: Did you run the installer using administrator?

Comment: yes i did, but still same error exist

Answer (score 0):

This version "android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows" has a problem so i tried my previous version "android-studio-bundle-141.2135290-windows" and it worked. Currently downloading SDK files...